# Why does WPF's Frame handle JavaScript differently from IE?

Tags: javascript, wpf, cross-browser

When I load an HTML page into a WPF `Frame` element, it runs the JavaScript differently than if I load the same page into a Web browser like IE. Why is that, and is there any way to make `Frame`'s behavior match the browser's?

If I load the following HTML into a Web browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
document.write('abc'[1])
</script>
```

it outputs `b` in Chrome, FireFox, Opera, and even IE. But if I load that same HTML into a WPF `Frame`:

```
<Frame Source="C:\Path\To\Page.htm" />
```

it outputs `undefined` instead.

Why the difference in behavior? I thought `Frame` was supposed to use Internet Explorer to render, but apparently it's doing something different.

If I leave off the `DOCTYPE` line, then IE also outputs `undefined` (though none of the other browsers do), which suggests that IE is using a different version of JavaScript (!) when the page doesn't declare itself to be HTML5. But then I would expect `Frame` to use the same logic, and clearly it does not -- it uses the older, not-supporting-string-indexing version of JavaScript even when I do declare the page to be HTML5.

What's going on to cause `Frame` to run the JavaScript differently than IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a lower engine. I assume you tested it on IE9? Well, IE9 broke away from the ActiveX control-style web browser. You need to use `'abc'.charAt(0)` instead of `abc[0]`.

Comment: It's too bad that they silently use an older version of IE, even when something better is available. But I guess it gives me an easy way to tell if my JavaScript would break in IE6...

Comment: @JoeWhite: Or IE8, for that matter... it's kind of sad to think that nothing was fixed for some 3 versions. (Also, something I didn't mention - I believe you can embed the WebKit engine in .NET. So if you need certain functionality, you can try that too. Not sure how well it works in WPF though.)